# Terminal transparency automatically achieved on certain color schemes, but not others

Tags: colorscheme

I've been trying different colour schemes while manually setting a transparent background using `hi Normal guibg=NONE ctermbg=NONE` so my `.vimrc` file looks something like this

```
set t_Co=256
colo mycolorscheme
hi Normal guibg=NONE ctermbg=NONE
```

and this works fine for some colour schemes but not for others. For those that don't work, I get a different coloured background.

Examples of colour schemes that worked for me are [Hybrid](http://vimcolors.com/34/hybrid/dark) and [onehalfdark](https://github.com/sonph/onehalf) and one example of theme that didn't work is the skin `base16-bright` from the [Base16 suite](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-vim)

However, when I manually enter `hi Normal guibg=NONE ctermbg=NONE` after vim has loaded, I can get a transparent terminal background.

Why is it that for some colour schemes, the transparency background is automatically done via `.vimrc` but not for some others?

Thanks!

Editted to add examples of colour schemes that work and don't.

Comment: Welcome Zili, you should extend your question and name color schemes that work and that don't.

Comment: Hey Ralf, thank you for your comment. I added some examples of colour schemes that work and don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no one, generic answer to your question. You'll need read the documentation for each color scheme that's giving you problems. For instance with Base16-Vim (which you linked as "Base16 suite") you'll find the following instructions for customizing the scheme

> If you want to do some local customization, you can add something like this to your ~/.vimrc:

```
function! s:base16_customize() abort
  call Base16hi("MatchParen", g:base16_gui05, g:base16_gui03, g:base16_cterm05, g:base16_cterm03, "bold,italic", "")
endfunction

augroup on_change_colorschema
  autocmd!
  autocmd ColorScheme * call s:base16_customize()
augroup END
```

Really you should read all of the documentation as the installation for some of these is not the usual "drop it in the colors dir".